Microsoft Teams Bot connector failing on certificate
Our Microsoft Teams integration is using the NodeJS botframework-connector library.
About half of the time however it won't respond to messages and we see the following in our logs:
request to https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/***/activities failed,
reason: unable to verify the first certificate
code: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
I have tried upgrading the library to the latest version, but this didn't help.

Is the CA certificate configured in node?

"unable to verify the first certificate" issue was resolved on last Tuesday that is on 9th July. We will check internally if this is a recent regression. Similar issue was reported here as well - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1804615/https-smba-trafficmanager-net-in-v3-conversations?comment=question#newest-question-comment

@Meghana-MSFT thank you! I can confirm the issue has now been resolved for us.
